# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' public' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '    public' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) on line 4

```
<?php
// Redirect Page Function
class Redirect {
    public function __construct($url = null) { \\ this is line 4 
        if ($url)
        {
            echo '<script>location.href="'.$url.'";</script>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have some weird character before public? Remove the indenting and see if it works

Comment: the comment isn't \\ its //

Comment: There is no syntax problem with the code posted once the irregular forward slashes are removed: https://3v4l.org/TueWb

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the comment and your code should work fine.

This is what you should remove:

\ this is line 4

Comment: In my code have no comment, i add it when i post the question !!